# Group JSON Data in Jquery usinng Underscore.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I would like to format my JSON data to display Chart in my reporting templates.I want to produce a daily reporting chart with date wise Approved, Rejected and Pending data. My current JSON is:

```
json_data = '[
                    {"Approved":1,"updated_date":"2015-03-07"}, 
                    {"Approved":1,"updated_date":"2015-03-07"}, 
                    {"Rejected":1,"updated_date":"2015-03-07"}, 
                    {"Pending":1,"updated_date":"2015-03-07"},{"Approved":1,"updated_date":"2015-03-07"}
                ]';
```

I want to achieve this output

```
$data=  '[
{
 "date": "1 Mar",
 "approved": 0,
 "completed": 0,
 "rejected": 0
},
{
 "date": "2 Mar",
 "approved": 0,
 "completed": 0,
 "rejected": 0
},
{
 "date": "3 Mar",
 "approved": 9,
 "completed": 20,
 "rejected": 11
},
{
 "date": "4 Mar",
 "approved": 20,
 "completed": 50,
 "rejected": 30
},
{
 "date": "5 Mar",
 "approved": 40,
 "completed": 50,
 "rejected": 10
},
{
 "date": "6 Mar",
 "approved": 35,
 "completed": 70,
 "rejected": 20
},
{
 "date": "7 Mar",
 "approved": 50,
 "completed": 80,
 "rejected": 30
}];'
```

I want to display only last 7 days data report through CHART.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first filter initial data by 'updated_date' (when the date is including in last 7 days), then group by 'updated_date' and then aggregate all desired properties by groups. Using underscore this will look something like this:

```
var json_data = '[{"Approved":1,"updated_date":"2015-03-07"}, {"Approved":1,"updated_date":"2015-03-07"}, {"Rejected":1,"updated_date":"2015-03-07"}, {"Pending":1,"updated_date":"2015-03-07"}, {"Approved":1,"updated_date":"2015-03-07"}, {"Approved":1, "Rejected": 1, "updated_date":"2015-03-08"}, {"Pending":17,"updated_date":"2015-03-02"} ]';

var json = JSON.parse(json_data);
var today = new Date('2015-03-10'); // new Date();
var sevenDays = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;

var result = _.map(_.groupBy(_.filter(json, function (item) {
    var dateDiff = today.getTime() - new Date(item.updated_date).getTime();
    return (dateDiff >= 0 && dateDiff < sevenDays);
}), 'updated_date'), function (g, key) {
    var res = _.reduce(g, function (memo, item) {
        return {
            approved: memo.approved + (item.Approved | 0),
            completed: memo.completed + (item.Completed | 0),
            rejected: memo.rejected + (item.Rejected | 0),
            pending: memo.pending + (item.Pending | 0),
        };
    }, { approved: 0, completed: 0, rejected: 0, pending: 0 });

    res.date = key;

    return res;
});
```

Here is a [Live demo in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1kw69qqp/)

For the sake of readability please use the good old for loops.

P.S. beware of JavaScript dates and time zones if you're doing this on client side.

Comment: Thanks Viktor! I also paste my code but your code gives better output.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sum(numbers) {
return _.reduce(numbers, function(result, current) {
    if(_.isUndefined(current))
        return result;
    return result + parseFloat(current);
}, 0);
}
var result = _.chain(json_data)
        .groupBy("updated_date")
        .map(function(value, key) {
            return {
                updated_date: key,
                Approved: sum(_.pluck(value, "Approved")),
                Rejected: sum(_.pluck(value, "Rejected")),
                Pending: sum(_.pluck(value, "Pending"))
            }
        })
        .last(7)
        .value();

    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```